# doctrine name convertions configuration

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

How can I configure doctrine to convert for example

```
/**
 * @var UuidInterface
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
 */
private $locationId;
```

to database column with name `location_id`, for some reason it creating name like `locationid` when I'm running `migrations:diff`. I know I can add `name="location_id"`, but is's annoying. I always use doctrine with Symfony and it automatically converts camel case to snake case. But now I'm using doctrine with a custom PHP application (not a framework), probably it can be configured somehow, but I can't find any related info in doctrine documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/namingstrategy.html it in the doctrine documentations